# Copy data from two sharepoint list into one

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I am using SharePoint Designer workflow to copy data from two identical list(with same column names) to another same list for backup purpose.
Backup list created using one of the list's template.

Issue is, data is getting copied but in destination list it has created duplicated columns. For e.g. i have Name, EmpId, Address columns in my source lists.
I am running workflow on above lists which is copying data to backup list. Now when workflow runs, backup lists get one more set of same columns created automatically. i.e. Name, EmpId, Address, Name, EmpId, Address. (though their internal names are different but display name is same)

List A data getting copied to fist set of columns and List B data getting copied other set of columns.

Any reason why? or workaround for this?

Comment: You need to have exactly the same Internal Names in both lists.

Comment: I do have, but workflow in B list copied its columns to backup list instead of copying data to existing columns. And these new copied columns obviously taking new names by appending 0.  I have tried it in with creating ideal scenario List A, B copying data to List C, and it is working fine. Only difference I see is my errord solution works on Information Policy Workflow.

Answer (score 0):

List B , which is created from other template should be exactly identical to List A.
Workaround: Create List B from List A template. This will solve your problem.